# number with decimal including all natural numbers

Tags: number-theory, terminology

I remember long time ago I faced with a question talking about real numbers which include all natural numbers in them after the decimal point. I don't remember the term for them and I cannot find them on web. Any help?

For example you if say $359$ then I can find it somewhere:

$6.21654651465414588954654321316498984813\color{red}{539}013518496846416\dots$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are called ['normal numbers'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number) (or at least i think that's what you mean :)) or you could even go to the more general ['disjunctive sequences'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_sequence).

Comment: One simple example is due to Champernowne: .012345678910111213..., where you just concatenate the numbers 0, 1, 2, ..., 9, 10, 11, ... after the decimal point.

Comment: does it grantee that all natural numbers would appear?

Comment: Yes: from my answer above: A disjunctive sequence is a sequence in which every finite string appears. A normal sequence is disjunctive, but a disjunctive sequence need not be normal. A rich number in base b is one whose expansion in base b is disjunctive.